# Django password field input showing up as plaintext despite forms.PasswordInput declaration

Tags: python, django, forms

Django password field input showing up as plaintext despite `widget=forms.PasswordInput` declaration:

## forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # specify password type so that passwords show up as *******, not plaintext
    # but this doesn't work if placeholder = ''
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "password"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first call the 'real' __init__()
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # then do extra stuff:
        self.fields['username'].help_text = ''
        self.fields['password'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': ''})
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

So interestingly, when I surface this form in a template, the `password` value shows up as plaintext instead of '******' text. But only if I add the `'placeholder': ''` line. I inspected the form element and figured out that when I added the  `'placeholder': ''` line, `type='password'` was being changed to `type='text'` in the `<input type='FOO'></input>`element in the rendered HTML.

--> How do I keep this from happening, so passwords continue to show up as plaintext, without removing my `'placeholder': ''` line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not be using `forms.TextInput` for your password field. [Django provides a PasswordInput widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#passwordinput) that is more appropriate. Try this:

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ["username", "password"]

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # first call the 'real' __init__()
    super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # then do extra stuff:
    self.fields['username'].help_text = ''
    self.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': ''})
    self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

While you can edit the type of the field manually, it's better convention to use the widget.

Comment: Nice; better than the answer I figured out!

Comment: (deleted my answer, as it didn't get to the root problem)

Comment: This is really cool. I used it in a different scenario though. Thanks.